# get_usermeta() deprecated in favor of get_user_meta(). But why doesn't it make use of it?

Tags: php, user-meta

While coding WP I just wondered about this simple fact:

`get_usermeta()` is deprecated since version 3.0. The warning suggests me to use `get_user_meta()`. Even the parameters are pretty similar, I wonder why the deprecated function is not making use of the new function as well.

Isn't that a sign that the new function does not really does what the deprecated did?

I'm wondering because I need to replace deprecated calls and wonder a bit.

What makes me even wondering more is the simple fact that `get_user_meta()` is quite an alias of the 2.9 function `get_metadata()` with only a constant value'ed parameter 'user' given.

Help ;)

***Edit:*** A counter-example is `clean_url()` - it's deprecated, the error message shows what this is about and the deprecated function aliases the new one: `esc_url()`, so it's clear what to do.

Comment: I don't think there's a hard-and-fast answer to this but it's an interesting question.

Comment: Yeah I am as well puzzled as curious at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `get_usermeta()` behaves differently from `get_user_meta()` and all the other `get_*_meta()` functions. That's why it was deprecated.

Unfortunately, the subtle differences couldn't be explained properly in a deprecation notice.

Comment: But probably you can here?

Comment: Comparing new and old version sources is always an option as well ... .